# Validating collections with FluentValidation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I am trying to do something like this :

```
RuleFor(client => client.PriceCustomization.GroupBy(a=>a.ProductId).Select(a => a.ToList()))
   .SetCollectionValidator(new PriceCustomizationsForProductValidator());
```

But I am receiving this error : Failed: System.InvalidOperationException : Nested validators can only be used with Member Expressions.

"*PriceCustomizationsForProductValidator*" is a validator for a List of "*PriceCustomization*"

Does anyone have any idea how could I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Using `FluentValidation` **version 8**, try this:

```
RuleForEach(client => client.PriceCustomization)
   .SetValidator(new PriceCustomizationsForProductValidator());
```

See https://fluentvalidation.net/upgrading-to-8.html

Answer (score 0):

If `PriceCustomizationsForProductValidator` is a validator for a list type then you don't need to call `.SetCollectionValidator`.  Instead you should be able to just call `.SetValidator`.